# Error 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Steps to reproduce the bug :

1.I am running the automation tests with the command :

testcafe chrome e2e-tests/fixtures/articles-table.ts

2.As soon as I am logged in the application , an error is shown ,which says "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5LdD.png)

3.I checked in the console the request: bad request 400 - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError

4.Four requests to the back end are failing ,giving the response:

Status Code: 400 Bad Request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mqyO.png)

5.The test I am actually trying to run is:

test.only("Articles table access", async t => {
await t.click(homePageView.productMenu)

await t.expect((articlesPageView.articleTable).exists).ok();

});

Environment details:

testcafe 1.9.2 version:

node.js version:

command-line arguments: testcafe chrome e2e-tests/fixtures/articles-table.ts

browser name and version: Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit)

platform and version:Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The [problem](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5499) with the same details was already reported in the TestCafe GitHub repository. All updates will be posted here. Please track the following thread to be informed about its progress: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5499.